# finite field arithemtic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following question. Let $A_1, A_2$ be elements in $F_{2^n}$. Let $M$ be an $n$ x $n$ matrix with elements in $Z_2$. I am looking for two $n$ x $n$ matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $Z_2$ such that for any $B_1, B_2 \in F_{2^n}$ the following holds:
$$ 
M_1 B_1 + M_2B_2 = M(A_1\cdot B_1 + A_2\cdot B_2).
$$
Notice that the definition of $M_1$ and $M_2$ can of course depend on $A_1$ and $A_2$. Notice further that on the left side of the equation we have a product of a matrix with a vector ($B_i$ is here represented as a $n$ dimensional vector of $Z_2$), while on the right hand side of the equation we *first* have a product and multiplication in the finite field, and then a matrix-vector multiplication. Dealing with these different representations is what makes it difficult for me to solve it.

Comment: $M_i$ is simply the matrix of the $\Bbb{Z}_2$-linear map $x \mapsto A_i \cdot x$. Clearly this depends on the choice of a basis, so a specific answer cannot be given.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my description since I forgot the $M$.

Comment: This does not change things. $M_i$ is the matrix of $x \mapsto M(A_i \cdot x)$.

Comment: Notice that you can easily unclutter the problem by observing that your equation can be replaced by two equations: $M_1 B_1 = M(A_1 \cdot B_1)$ for any $B_1$, and $M_2 B_2 = M(A_2 \cdot B_2)$ for any $B_2$. Your equation follows from these two, and these two follow from your equation if you take one of $B_1$, $B_2$ to be equal to $0$.

Comment: @Crostul: I am not sure I understand what you mean with your comment regarding the basis.

Comment: @Tom Matrix notation makes no sense if you don't fix a basis. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFkZGpN4wmM) for a (long but exquisite) explanation.

Comment: @Crostul: I watched the video. It is really nice, but still I do not get what additional information you need from me :(

Comment: When you say that "$B_i$ is represented as a $n$-dimensional vector of $Z_2$" you forget that such a representation is possible only when a basis of $F_{2^n}$ is fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I understand now. So the base would be ${1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7}$. Does this make sense?